# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null at changeTW (<anonymous>:30:16) at HTMLInputElement.onclick (192.168.1.113/:1)

Tags: javascript, html, css

My web get a mistakes with "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null".

### In my nav.html,this is my code :

```
<li id="nav-AI" role="presentation" style="display: none"><a href="/AIMakerSpace">AI Maker Space</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/AIMakerSpace">關於AIMS</a></li>
        <li><a href="/support-TW">技術支持</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

---

### In my header.html,when I click the "changeCN",my "nav-AI" will show, the code is :

```
<div class="dropdown">
<img id="speakchange" src="images/speakchange.png" alt="" onclick="menu.style.display='block';">
<div id="menu">
     <ul class="nostyle" role="menu">
         <li><input id="changeCN" type="button" value="简体" onclick="changeCN()"></li>
         <li><input id="changeTW" type="button" value="繁体" onclick="changeTW()"></li>
         <li><input id="changeEN" type="button" value="英文" onclick="changeEN()"></li>
     </ul>
 </div>
 </div>
```

---

My js is :

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeCN() {
        document.getElementById("changeCN");
        TAPi18n.setLanguage('en');
        var obd=document.getElementById("body");
        obd.style.fontFamily="'Microsoft YaHei',SimSun,Verdana,simsun,sans-serif";
        document.getElementById("nav-AI").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("logo").src="images/Geometric.png";
    }
    function changeEN() {
        document.getElementById("changeEN");
        TAPi18n.setLanguage('cn');
        var obd=document.getElementById("body");
        obd.style.fontFamily="'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif";
        document.getElementById("nav-AI").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("logo").src="images/Geometric-TW.png";
    }
    function changeTW() {
        document.getElementById("changeTW");
        TAPi18n.setLanguage('tw');
        var obd=document.getElementById("body");
        obd.style.fontFamily="'Microsoft JhengHei',SimSun，Verdana,sans-serif";
        document.getElementById("nav-AI").style.display="inline";
        document.getElementById("logo").src="images/Geometric-TW.png";
    }
    window.onload=function() {
        changeCN();
        changeEN();
        changeTW();
    }
</script>
```

---

I use "window.onload",but it didn't work，I don't konw how to solve it.

Comment: Have u given id for body tag, then only this "document.getElementById("body")" will work; if not use "document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]". please check

Comment: An alternative, `document.querySelector('body')`. Also @nivendha, it shoulf be `('body')[0]`

Comment: @nivendha @Rajesh To access the body, just use `document.body`. Simple!